# Vscode frontend link with springboot

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I built my frontend with vscode (html,sass and js node modules) and my backend with springboot. How do i link my springboot backend to my vscode frontend?

Comment: you need to create the API in spring boot and consume that api in the front end

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: have you used any front end framework?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Develop all your necessary API's with spring boot for getting backend data. Then, to get the data in frontend you can use ExpressJs (web application framework for Node.js).

Answer (score 0):

To connnect your SpringBoot Backend Server with your SpringBoot Running Application let's Say At localhost 8080 then you just Have to know your Backend Api's are working or not for that Postman is the best tool. then As you said you have the data but you just have to post or get it from server then you can use XML Http Request from you frontend at Specific URL, And will surely get the payload/ Post it to the server here is XML Http Request Example:-

```
// Define the data you want to send to the server
const dataToSend = {
  name: "John Doe",
  email: "johndoe@example.com",
};

// Create a new XMLHttpRequest object
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

 
xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/api/create", true);


xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 
xhr.onload = function () {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    // Request was successful, handle the response data here
    const responseData = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log("Response from server:", responseData);
  } else {
    // Request encountered an error, handle the error here
    console.error("Error:", xhr.status, xhr.statusText);
  }
};

 
xhr.onerror = function () {
  console.error("Network error occurred");
};

 
const jsonData = JSON.stringify(dataToSend);

 
xhr.send(jsonData);
```

Don't forget to Stringify your data for converting to JSON Format .

It's Just One Working Way to Connect Front-End With SpringBoot Application.

HAPPY LEARNING.:)